# Getting empty response from web service build with php

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, soap

I wanted to create a web service with php and zend framework.
The server side code is as follow:

**csiService.php:**

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
require_once 'CSI.php';
$WSDL_URI="http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php?WSDL";
if(isset($_GET["WSDL"]))
{
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Soap_Wsdl_Strategy_ArrayOfTypeSequence');
    $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover('Zend_Soap_Wsdl_Strategy_ArrayOfTypeSequence'); 
    $autodiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document')); 
    $autodiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal')); 
    $autodiscover->setClass('CSI'); 
    $autodiscover->handle();
} 
else
{
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Soap_Server');
    $server = new Zend_Soap_Server($WSDL_URI);
    $server->setClass('CSI');
    $server->handle();
}
?>
```

Which includes the **CSI.php**:

```
<?php
class CSI {
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    function helloWorld()
    {
        return("Hello");
    }
}
?>
```

**I edited the host file, in order to bind the domain "csi.chemicalseeker.com" to 127.0.0.1*
The WSDL just works well as I visit "http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php?WSDL" in my browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="CSI"
    targetNamespace="http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php">
            <xsd:element name="helloWorld">
                <xsd:complexType />
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="helloWorldResponse">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="helloWorldResult" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <portType name="CSIPort">
        <operation name="helloWorld">
            <documentation>@return string</documentation>
            <input message="tns:helloWorldIn" />
            <output message="tns:helloWorldOut" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="CSIBinding" type="tns:CSIPort">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="helloWorld">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php#helloWorld" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="CSIService">
        <port name="CSIPort" binding="tns:CSIBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php" />
        </port>
    </service>
    <message name="helloWorldIn">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloWorld" />
    </message>
    <message name="helloWorldOut">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloWorldResponse" />
    </message>
</definitions>
```

I also wrote a php client file called CSIClient.php and visited it from the browser:

**CSIClient.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
require_once 'CSI.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Soap_Client');
$WSDL_URI="http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php?WSDL";

    $client = new Zend_Soap_Client($WSDL_URI);
    echo('<pre>');
    var_dump($client->helloWorld());
    echo('</pre>');
?>
```

The result is expected to be a string with the content of "Hello", but it shows an empty stdObject:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (0) {
}
```

I can get the function list and type list via "$client->getFunctions()" and "$client->getTypes()", it means the "CSI" class has been connected to the web service successfully. But the result can not be returned correctly.

I've also tried other methods to invoke the web service. I used Flash Builder to call the helloWorld() function, the response from server is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://csi.chemicalseeker.com/csiService.php">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:helloWorldResponse/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As we can see that the expected result "Hello" is not included in the SOAP envelope either.
Did I missed something important or made some mistakes in my code? Help me please if you have a clue. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I am struggling with this as well but I managed to solve the issue you are having above by switching to Non-WSDL mode.

No matter what I tried I always received the same empty response you are when attempting to load the WSDL from my own autodiscovery generated WSDL.   (It feels like there may be some recursion problem, but I cannot see how right now)

Regardless, switching to non WSDL mode gave me proper responses.

try creating your Server as follows:

```
$server = new Zend_Soap_Server(null, array('uri' => $WSDL_URI));
```

Comment: I'm sorry this answer is so fortunated. It seems Soap Server fails handling the return of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your php error log while doing the tests.

You can also enable error_reporting `E_STRICT` or `E_NOTICE` to get more informative error hints:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php

And with [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) you can do more extensible tests: